# Spring security annotations work perfectly in the external Chrome browser but not in the integrated eclipse STS navigator

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-tool-suite

It is not a problem to continue coding, but I'm worry about the security.

I don't know which could be the problem, or in which part could it be. This the whole code: https://www.assembla.com/code/proyectoiw/subversion/nodes/32/Alojamiento

UPDATE 1.

Annotations in a controller like:

```
@Secured(["hasAnyRole('ROL_ADMIN','ROL_SUPERADMIN','ROL_USUARIO')"])
```

Or in a view like:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROL_SUPERADMIN">
```

Both work perfectly in chrome, but not inside the integrated browser of Eclipse STS. It happens also in my computer classmate.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how they're not working?

Comment: sure! I updated the question (UPDATE 1)

Comment: What I meant was: What happens in the STS browser that is incorrect?

Comment: STS shows the stuff that that should be hidden because of these annotations.